# Remove first n lines from file with variable

Tags: shell-script, sed

The command below works for deleting the first 3 lines:

```
sed -i -e 1,3d t.txt
```

So I tried substituting the 3 with a variable in a script as below

```
NrLines=$(wc -l t.txt)
sed -i -e 1,"$NrLines{d}" t.txt
```

and get following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unexpected `}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems command substitution and braces are misused.

```
NrLines=$(wc -l < t.txt)
sed -i -e 1,"${NrLines}d" t.txt
```

Comment: this didn't work in `bash` for me. I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: extra characters after command`

Comment: Updated.  Because `wc -l t.txt` prints something like `123 t.txt`.

Comment: How can I divide the $NrLines by 2 in the 2nd line so it removes the first half of the file?

Comment: You can perform simple arithmetic operations with bash: `NrLines=$(( $(wc -l < t.txt) / 2 ))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using `tail` (this is not optimal for large files):

```
NrLines=3
<<< "$(< t.txt)" tail -n +$((NrLines+1)) > t.txt
```

Comment: The command substitution on `t.txt` will cause the trailing newline from the file to disappear in its output